# MSSQL and POSTGRESQL common string filter expression for the index - efcore code-first

Tags: c#, sql-server, postgresql, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I have a problem with HasFilter method.I could not configure the filter expression for Index in different databases.

This line just works with MSSQL

```
builder.HasIndex(p => new { p.Name, p.Id })
                    .HasFilter($"{nameof(Entity.IsDeleted)} = 0").IsUnique(true);
```

This line just works with PostgreSQL

```
builder.HasIndex(p => new { p.Name, p.Id })
                    .HasFilter("\"IsDeleted\" = false").IsUnique(true);
```

Is there a common syntax for HasFilter ?

Answer (score 0):

No because the dataypes are different. MS SQL use a bit that have 0 and 1 values for boolean, while PostgreSQL use a boolean that have true and false values.

I am writing a series of paper on the differences betwwen SQL Server and PostgreSQL. [This first one speaks about performances of DBA queries](http://mssqlserver.fr/postgresql-vs-microsoft-sql-server-comparison-part-1-count-and-dba-command-performances/), the second to come about performances of COUNT and the third compares functionalities...